# Configure Different Tax Rates for Defferent Countries

Tags: magento, magento2, tax

I need a little help regarding Tax configuration in `Magento2`. My tax configuration scenario is we ship in around 10 countries and we don't want to charge Tax from customers except for Pakistan, which is our local market. Can someone suggest me how can I set different tax rates for every country.

Here is how the rate sheet is

```
|  Country |  Rate Percent |
|----------|---------------|
|  US      |   0           |
|  CA      |   0           |
|  PK      |   5           |
```

If the customer is from Pakistan we will be charging 5% tax rate. otherwise it's 0

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a tax rate of 0 for each country. In **Stores > Tax Zones and Rates**. Once you have created those 10 zones & rates you need to created a new Rule.

In **Stores > Tax Rule** you create/edit a rule & make sure all 10 tax rates are selected. 
In these tax rule create a new tax class named as you wish. Select only that class tax.

Now in your products check that the tax class is the one you selected in the rule.

Now the proper tax should apply when the customer chooses his address in the checkout.